# Stepping through Plist and writing

Tags: swift

I created a app for personal use to write data into two Plist files from a template in my BundlePath.
was working great until Swift 3 and i'm unsure about passing the index of the template as the key.

```
for index in 0 ..< number {


        var diction = (resultQDictionary?.object(forKey: "Questions"))

        print("diction = \(diction)")

//PROBLEM HERE!! - cannot call value of non function type 'Any?!' for dictionaryQItem and dictionaryAItem 

        var dictionaryQItem = (resultQDictionary?.object(forKey: "Questions") as AnyObject).object(index)
        var dictionaryAItem = (resultADictionary?.object(forKey: "Answers") as AnyObject).object(index)

        print("dQitem = \(dictionaryQItem)")

        //print("this is DI for question = \(dictionaryItem?.objectForKey("Question"))")
        //print(dictionaryItem?.objectForKey("Title"))



        var cAns = inputSheetObjectArrayKey[index] //c
        var quest = questionArray[index]
        var title = titleArray[index]
        var block = pickerBlock // blockArray[index]

        var answerA = answerAArray[index]
        var answerB = answerBArray[index]
        var answerC = answerCArray[index]

        //print("quest = \(quest)")

        let trimmedcAns = (cAns as AnyObject).trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
        let trimmedQuest = quest.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
        let trimmedTitle = title.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
        //let trimmedBlock = block.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
        let trimmedAnswerA = answerA.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
        let trimmedAnswerB = answerB.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
        let trimmedAnswerC = answerC.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)



        dictionaryQItem.setValue(trimmedcAns, forKey: "CorrectAnswer")
        dictionaryQItem.setValue(trimmedQuest, forKey: "Question")
        dictionaryQItem.setValue(trimmedTitle, forKey: "Title")
        dictionaryQItem.setValue(pickerBlock, forKey: "Block")



        dictionaryAItem.setValue(trimmedAnswerA, forKey: "A")
        dictionaryAItem.setValue(trimmedAnswerB, forKey: "B")
        dictionaryAItem.setValue(trimmedAnswerC, forKey: "C")
        dictionaryAItem.setValue(trimmedTitle, forKey: "Title")
        dictionaryAItem.setValue(" ", forKey: "FEEDBACK")


    }

    resultQDictionary?.write(toFile: docsQPath, atomically: false)
    resultADictionary?.write(toFile: docsAPath, atomically: false)


}
```

cannot call value of non function type 'Any?!' for dictionaryQItem and dictionaryAItem - was working great in Swift 2.3 but i'm unsure how to pass in the index. Any help appreciated!

Comment: What's the Type of resultQDictionary and resultADictionary?

Comment: BTW, `AnyObject` only works for classes. If you could be working with structs, (String, Int, etc.) you should use `Any`

Comment: In Swift 3 the compiler needs to know the type of all subscripted objects (that includes also `objectForKey / Index`). You need to cast `resultQDictionary?["Questions"]` to the proper type (which is not recognizable in the code). And use key subscripting rather than `objectForKey`. Finally `AnyObject` has been changed to `Any` for json and plist dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I'd define DictionaryAItem and DictionaryQItem as class objects and use them to manage the Questions and Answers data especially as you seem to have well defined structures.